# perl join strings incorrectly

Tags: string, perl

I have a list of authors like this:

```
AU  - Garrett-Bakelman, Francine E
AU  - Sheridan, Caroline K
AU  - Kacmarczyk, Thadeous J
AU  - Ishii, Jennifer
AU  - Betel, Doron
AU  - Alonso, Alicia
AU  - Mason, Christopher E
AU  - Figueroa, Maria E
AU  - Melnick, Ari M
```

which I read with a perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;
my @authors;
open my $fh, '<', '/home/con/Downloads/pmcid-PMC4354670.ris' or die "Can't read file: $!";
while (<$fh>) {
    if ($_ =~ m/^AU\s+-         #line starts with 'AU'
    \s+                         #whitespace
    (.*)                        #author is represented by non-newline characters, saved as $1
    /x) {
        push @authors, $1;
    }   
}
close $fh;
printf("there are %u authors\n", scalar @authors);
foreach my $author (@authors) {
    print "$author\n";#prints each element correctly
}
print "@authors\n";#but prints the concatenation incorrectly, 'Melnick, Ari Ma Er E Jine E'
print join ' and ', @authors;#prints 'and Melnick, Ari Ma Er E JE'
```

I cannot get the list of strings to be joined correctly.
I have tried the 'join' function, concatenating a string as I'm reading the code, it's always a mishmash.

How can I get the array of strings to be concatenated correctly?

Comment: Please comment all `print` and run again since it works fine.

Comment: perhaps I wasn't clear, it can print each array element correctly, but cannot join or concatenate the array correctly.

Comment: what was your expecting output?

Comment: Output `print`'s like `Garrett-Bakelman, Francine E and Sheridan, Caroline K and Kacmarczyk, Thadeous J and Ishii, Jennifer and Betel, Doron and Alonso, Alicia and Mason, Christopher E and Figueroa, Maria E and Melnick, Ari M`

Comment: @ssr1012 yes that is the correct output.  I'm worried because I don't understand why perl isn't concatenating the string or joining the string the way it has before (as I understood it, which is evidently wrong)

Comment: I should think now its ok for you.

Comment: Maybe it's a bug related to your perl version? What version of the intereptor do you use?

Comment: @ssr1012 the correct output is not printed.  Perl is printing mishmash, which can be seen in the comments.

I'm using Perl 5.22.1 built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi

Comment: Btw, you don't need `$_ =~ m...` -- just `if (/^AU\s+-\s+(.*)/)` does it and is a idiomatic. Once you _are_ having it assign to `$_` with `(<$fh>)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your regex to this. This works with both DOS and UNIX formatted text files.

```
if ($_ =~ m/^AU\s+-         #line starts with 'AU'
\s+                         #whitespace
([^\r\n]*)                  #author is represented by non-newline characters, saved as $1
/x) {
```

Answer (score 3):

your file `/home/con/Downloads/pmcid-PMC4354670.ris` should be converted from DOS convention to standard using the `dos2unix` command

The trailing character '\r' at the end of the string is the cause of your problems.

Answer (score 1):

Further to BOC's answer, you can solve it without dos2unix by changing the `<` in your open call to `<:crlf`:

```
open my $fh, '<:crlf', '/home/con/Downloads/pmcid-PMC4354670.ris';
```

Perl then ["converts pairs of CR,LF to a single "\n" newline character"](http://perldoc.perl.org/PerlIO.html).

Or you can add `/r/n` to the end of your regex:

```
print join ' and ', map { /\AAU  - (.*)\r\n/ } <$fh>;
```

Comment: Or you can add `s/\s+\z//g;` at the top of the loop.

Comment: Interesting, because CR is whitespace? Do you know why it doesn't work with `\r` instead of `\s`?

Comment: Did you account for the `\n`?